prove that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, F(2n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} F(2i-1).$ Here, $F(n)$ is the Fibonacci sequence
Question:

Prove that every even indexed Fibonacci number is the sum of all the odd indexed Fibonacci
numbers that precede it. I.e., prove that $$\forall n \in \mathbb{N}, F(2n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} F(2i-1)$$

My work:
$$ \text{Let } P(n): F(2n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n} F(2i-1) \forall n \in \mathbb{N}$$
$$\text{Base Case: } P(1): F(2) = 1 = \sum_{i=1}^1 F(2-1)$$
P(1) base case holds
Induction Step:

$$ \text{I.H assume } P(k) \forall 1 \ge k < n$$

$$\text{WTS: }P(n+1): F(2n+2) = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} F(2i-1)$$
$$F(2n+2) = F(2n+1) + F(2n) \text{ [by defn. of Fibonacci sequence]}$$
$$ = F(2n+1) + \sum_{i=1}^{n} F(2i-1) \text{ [by i.H]}$$
$$ \text{... (idk)}$$
$$ = \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} F(2i-1)$$
the "... (idk)" part is where I get stuck.
I'm unsure if my induction stmnt is correct, I'm unsure if I started the induction step correctly (ur supposed to start w/ what is true, and technically the first stmnt is true so...?)
any guidance is appreciated. ty
Edit: From another post,
That's basically my sols, but I dont understand how they went from
$$f_{2k + 1} + \sum_{i = 1}^k f_{2i - 1}$$
to
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} f_{2i - 1}$$

That's basically my sols, but I dont understand how he went from
$$f_{2k + 1} + \sum_{i = 1}^k f_{2i - 1}$$
to
$$ \sum_{i = 1}^{k + 1} f_{2i - 1}$$

What's to understand? In the one, you're adding up the first $k$ odd-index Fibonaccis, and then adding on the next one; in the second, you're adding up the first $k+1$ odd-index Fibonaccis. Same thing!

Note that $2(i+1)-1=2i+1$

It was staring me right in my face! Spending 5+ hrs on a pset is not good for you at all.
Thanks!
